# Realizar evento onclick en un radio button de contact form 7 wordpres

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Estoy haciendo un formulario y lo que quiero hacer es cuando clican en un radiobuton salgan otros apartados para rellenar si no clican que no salgan, esto lo puedo hacer con javascripot y el evento onclick pero en contact form 7 como lo haría? ya que el onclick="" no funciona.

tengo este codigo en javascript

```
function mostrarCiudad(){

if (document.getElementById('notariosno').click == true;) {

document.getElementById('ciudadnotario').style.display='block';
} else {

document.getElementById('ciudadnotario').style.display='none';
}
}
```

Gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes copiar el código aquí para que lo veamos?

Answer (score 1):

Ya esta solucionado.

Lo que he cambiado era checked y he quitado el ; despues del true.
el codigo era el siguiente:

```
function mostrarCiudad(){

if (document.getElementById('notariosno').checked == true) {

document.getElementById('ciudadnotario').style.display='block';
} else {

document.getElementById('ciudadnotario').style.display='none';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lo puedes hacer con jQuery. 
1º) saca el código HTML del formulario en una pagina HTML aparte para probar
2º) en esa pagina html, crea el script jquery para controlar el onclick del radiobutton y que haga lo que tenga que hacer (ocultar los campos que quieras) 
3º) una vez que te funcione en local, coge el script que has creado y ponlo en el archivo footer.php de tu plantilla y listo.

No se si Contact form te permite controlar eso, pero si no puedes buscar otros componentes que si te permiten lógica en los campos.

A ver si te ayuda

Comment: Gracias, buscare si se puede poner javascript en contactform7